# java spring: how to access Application Context of another Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-integration

I have two separate spring boot(Maven) application ORAApp1 & CASApp1. I have both app running on separate cloud instance.
In my CASApp1 i need to get beans from application context of ORAApp1.

Want to know if this is possible or not and if so, how it can be done.

Thanks,
Atul.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why exactly you need to access beans of another application? Is there any way to Organize REST communication between two process and allow access to functionality rather than using beans directly? This might be an answer to your question

Comment: Thanks for response, Actually these are GRPC applications, and i dont intend to create another grpc service, unless it is must. So just wanted to check possibility of accessing the beans, rather than building proto / grpc code around same. Also i want to do it for multiple beans, so may need to expose more grpc service in case i have to do it over grpc/rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot application doesn't expose beans to be consumed by other applications, so you can't really do that.
Spring boot application by design is "self-contained" and beans are not "exposed services" but internal building blocks of the application that implement the business logic of your app.

This is a design of all spring applications.

In general, Spring is something that "lives" inside the JVM however you run two different JVM processes so you'll have to do some kind of inter-process communication between them.

Also, it's a good idea to "control" what functions are exposed to be used by other applications and how (protocol, parameters, results, etc).

Luckily spring boot application allows to easily establish such control by using controllers of spring-MVC. So basically you mark a bean with a couple of annotations (bean = a class managed by spring and allows injection of other spring beans) and it gets exposed (by some URL) automatically. This is the closest "spring-ish" way to achieve what you want.

Of course, if you need a GRPC style of inter-process communication you definitely can create GRPC services.

There are also other ways that can be used in different use cases (for example for management you might opt for JMX) or some kind of message bus for asynchronous communication, but this is a topic too broad to be discussed in one question.  Bottom line, this is not "automatic" and you have to choose the style of IPC that works for your case, but definitely, you need to have **something** and you can't just "call" the beans as long as you have two different applications that run on two different JVMs (and it doesn't really matter whether they're running on the same host or not).

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible** in your case. Here you have 2 different cloud instances, which means 2 different JVM and 2 different spring containers.

If you want to instantiate multiple `ApplicationContexts` in your application. It will be in a parent-child hierarchy. There will be one root `ApplicationContext` & then there will be a few child `ApplicationContext` respective to every `DispatcherServlet`. Beans global to the application will be defined in the root `ApplicationContext`. All the `ApplicationContexts` will be managed by only one spring container running on a single JVM.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly get the beans from one spring boot app to another.

**The ApplicationContext Interface**

> The Spring IoC container is responsible for managing the objects of an
> application. It uses dependency injection to achieve inversion of
> control. The interfaces BeanFactory and ApplicationContext represent
> the Spring IoC container

The web applications are containerized in spring and you cannot regularly share variables with different applications/containers. You can have two contexts within an application If you have two contexts each will have its own singleton.

Workaround:

You can try to use the same mechanism as you use to communicate between two services. eg. REST API

To get beans from the application context.

```
 @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(ApplicationContext appContext) {
        return args -> {

            String[] beans = appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
            Arrays.stream(beans).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);

        };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for response, can you please share more details on / any example on this. (Workaround)

Comment: https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/how-to-display-all-beans-loaded-by-spring-boot/#:~:text=In%20Spring%20Boot%2C%20you%20can,loaded%20by%20the%20Spring%20container.

Comment: Thanks, i had been through this, but not sure, if it would help me access context of another Spring Application.